# jquery to find data-attr where

Tags: jquery

Using the url of the page I have been able to get the value edc into a variable but what I need to do is find the data-ttl where data-uri is equal to edc.

If PHP this would be easy but I'm unsure how to go about it in jQuery

> domain.com/media-centre/video/edc

**HTML**

```
            <li class="item" data-id="id-7" data-type="services">
            <a href="#" data-uri='edc' data-ttl='Engineering'>
                    <img src="/assets/img/media-centre/videos/edc.png">
                    <div class="itemcontent">
                        <h2>Engineering</h2>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
```

**JQUERY - my tried and failed attempt**

```
var permatitle = $('a').attr('data-uri').val('edc');
```

**SORTED**

> var permatitle = $('a[data-uri="edc"]').attr('data-ttl');

Comment: The [jQuery data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method abstracts some of this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this selector:

```
$('a[data-uri="edc"]')
```

Then you can read data attribute like:

```
$('a[data-uri="edc"]').data('edc')
```

Comment: How would I be able to pick up data-ttl from the above?